# Package contents hidden after github merge

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

I was using Github and Git to upload a repo and the code from my intellij Packages using command line.

I must have done a merge or a pull request or something along that line, when my classes just randomly disappeared from the package like so:

[Packages](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe2evu70giu1w0q/Screenshot%202014-11-02%2017.42.40.png?dl=0)

But the classes are in the packages when viewed from file explorer seen here:

[File Explorer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hq32g75xr3xhq3/Screenshot%202014-11-02%2017.52.06.png?dl=0)

I have tried creating new files, adding some text, saving, pushing to github, and it works fine, so maybe intellij is trying to hide the files? I have tried playing with my project settings and anything else I can think of.

I do not really think it is a Git or Github issue as much as it is something Intellij related. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you update your question to make the screenshots inline?

Comment: I would need at least 10 rep which I do not have. @hlovdal